# Is there something wrong with this Ajax call?

Tags: php, ajax

I have this Ajax call which submits a form and shows different things depending on the response from the server:

```
$('#applyForm').submit(function(){
var dataString = $(this).serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/common/apply/apply.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data) {
        if(data=='1'){
            $('#formDiv').fadeOut();
            $('#ok').fadeIn();
        }
        else if(data=='0') {
            $('#warning').fadeIn();
        }
        else if(data=='-1') {
            $('#error').fadeIn();
        }
        else {
            alert(data);
        }
    }
});
return false 
});
```

Is this the correct way of doing it?!

Thanks!

Comment: can you post what the return data is?

Comment: You missedd `event.preventDefault()` after datastring. Without that... it will submit the form before making the ajax request.

Comment: The weird thing is that the php script returns "1" but nothing happens in the front-end. That is to say <div id="ok"></div> doesn't show. It only alerts the response which is "1". Any ideas on that?

Comment: I don't know how javascript feels about 1=='1', but you might need to make sure everything is a string, or everything is an int.  Also: Are you sure data isn't holding more information than just 1?  Anything else echo'd on the apply.php page will also be a part of the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the alert is showing `1` then the response doesn't equal any of the condition checks. I think you have some whitespace at the beginning or end of the response causing the `data == '1'` check to evaluate to `false`.

Try trimming your response on the PHP side, or do it on the Javascript side like:

```
success: function(data) {

    data = $.trim(data);

    if(data=='1'){
        $('#formDiv').fadeOut();
        $('#ok').fadeIn();
    }
    else if(data=='0') {
        $('#warning').fadeIn();
    }
    else if(data=='-1') {
        $('#error').fadeIn();
    }
    else {
        alert(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely have the right idea.  Call .ajax to send the request, use a success handler to deal with the response.  The syntax might not be 100% on, but as far as 'is this the correct way of doing it?!' - YES

Comment: The weird thing is that the php script returns "1" but nothing happens in the front-end. That is to say <div id="ok"></div> doesn't show. It only alerts the response which is "1". Any ideas on that?